# How to efficiently and correctly implement numba jit decorator or apply vectorization instead of a for loop to speed up the program execution?

Tags: pandas, numpy, optimization, vectorization, numba

Atttempted to implement jit decorator to increase the speed of execution of my code. Not getting proper results. It is throughing all sorts of errors.. Key error, type errors, etc..
The actual code without numba is working without any issues.

```
# The Code without numba is:
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Serial'] = [865,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,875,876,877,878,879,880]
df['Value'] = [586,586.45,585.95,585.85,585.45,585.5,586,585.7,585.7,585.5,585.5,585.45,585.3,584,584,585]
df['Ref'] = [586.35,586.1,586.01,586.44,586.04,585.91,585.47,585.99,585.35,585.27,585.32,584.86,585.36,584.18,583.53,585]
df['Base'] = [0,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,-1]

df['A'] = 0.0
df['B'] = 0.0
df['Counter'] = 0
df['Counter'][0] = df['Serial'][0]

for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
    # Filling Column 'A'
    if (df.iloc[1+i,2] > df.iloc[1+i,1]) & (df.iloc[i,5] > df.iloc[1+i,1]) & (df.iloc[1+i,3] >0):
        df.iloc[1+i,4] = round((df.iloc[1+i,1]*1.02),2)
    elif (df.iloc[1+i,2] < df.iloc[1+i,1]) & (df.iloc[i,5] < df.iloc[1+i,1]) & (df.iloc[1+i,3] <0):
        df.iloc[1+i,4] = round((df.iloc[1+i,1]*0.98),2)
    else:
        df.iloc[1+i,4] = df.iloc[i,4]
    # Filling Column 'B'
    df.iloc[1+i,5] = round(((df.iloc[1+i,1] + df.iloc[1+i,2])/2),2) 
    # Filling Column 'Counter'
    if (df.iloc[1+i,5] > df.iloc[1+i,1]):
        df.iloc[1+i,6] = df.iloc[1+i,0]
    else:
        df.iloc[1+i,6] = df.iloc[i,6]
df
```

The below code is giving me the error. where i tried to implement numba jit decorator to speed up the original python code.

```
#The code with numba jit which is throwing error is:
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Serial']=[865,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,875,876,877,878,879,880]
df['Value']=[586,586.45,585.95,585.85,585.45,585.5,586,585.7,585.7,585.5,585.5,585.45,585.3,584,584,585]
df['Ref']=[586.35,586.1,586.01,586.44,586.04,585.91,585.47,585.99,585.35,585.27,585.32,584.86,585.36,584.18,583.53,585]
df['Base'] = [0,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,-1]
from numba import jit
@jit(nopython=True)
def Calcs(Serial,Value,Ref,Base):
    n = Base.size
    A = np.empty(n, dtype='f8')
    B = np.empty(n, dtype='f8')
    Counter = np.empty(n, dtype='f8')
    A[0] = 0.0
    B[0] = 0.0
    Counter[0] = Serial[0]
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        # Filling Column 'A'
        if (Ref[i+1] > Value[i+1]) & (B[i] > Value[i+1]) & (Base[i+1] > 0):
            A[i+1] = round((Value[i+1]*1.02),2)
        elif (Ref[i+1] < Value[i+1]) & (B[i] < Value[i+1]) & (Base[i+1] < 0):  
            A[i+1] = round((Value[i+1]*0.98),2)
        else:
            A[i+1] = A[i]
        # Filling Column 'B'
        B[i+1] = round(((Value[i+1] + Ref[i+1])/2),2)
        # Filling Column 'Counter'
        if (B[i+1] > Value[i+1]):
            Counter[i+1] = Serial[i+1]
        else:
            Counter[i+1] = Counter[i]   
    List = [A,B,Counter]        
    return List

Serial = df['Serial'].values.astype(np.float64)
Value = df['Value'].values.astype(np.float64)
Ref = df['Ref'].values.astype(np.float64)
Base = df['Base'].values.astype(np.float64)

VCal = Calcs(Serial,Value,Ref,Base)

df['A'].values[:] = VCal[0].astype(object)
df['B'].values[:] = VCal[1].astype(object)
df['Counter'].values[:] = VCal[2].astype(object)
df
```

I tried to modify the code as per the guidance provided by @Jérôme Richard for the question [How to Eliminate for loop in Pandas Dataframe in filling each row values of a column based on multiple if,elif statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71458405/how-to-eliminate-for-loop-in-pandas-dataframe-in-filling-each-row-values-of-a-co).

But getting the errors and am Unable to correct the code. Looking for some help from the community in correcting & improving the above code or to find an even better code to enhance the speed of execution.
The expected outcome of the code is shown in the below pic.
[image]

Comment: Please provide the error (as people may get different error regarding the version of packages or even no error in some case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `df['A'].values[:]` if the column `A` exists in the dataframe. Otherwise you need to create a new one, possibly with `df['A'] = ...`.

Moreover, the trick with `astype(object)` applies for string but not for numbers. Indeed, string-based dataframe columns do apparently not use Numpy string-based array but Numpy object-based arrays containing CPython strings. For numbers, Pandas properly uses number-based arrays. Converting numbers back to object is inefficient. The same applies for `astype(np.float64)`: it is not needed if the time is already fine. This is the case here. If you are unsure about the input type, you can let them though as they are not very expensive.

The Numba function itself is fine (at least with a recent version of Numba). Note that you can specify the signature to [compile the function eagerly](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jit.html). This feature also help you to catch typing errors sooner and make them a bit more clear. The downside is that it makes the function less generic as only specific types are supported (though you can specify multiple signatures).

```py
from numba import njit

@njit('List(float64[:])(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:], float64[:])')
def Calcs(Serial,Value,Ref,Base):
    [...]

Serial = df['Serial'].values
Value = df['Value'].values
Ref = df['Ref'].values
Base = df['Base'].values

VCal = Calcs(Serial, Value, Ref, Base)

df['A'] = VCal[0]
df['B'] = VCal[1]
df['Counter'] = VCal[2]
```

Note that you can use the Numba decorator flag `fastmath=True` to speed up the computation if you are sure that the input array never contains spacial values like NaN or Inf or -0, and you do not rely on FP-math associativity.

Comment: Thank you Jérôme Richard. I tried the mentioned changes. But getting this error. TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No conversion from list(array(float64, 1d, C))<iv=None> to list(array(float64, 1d, A))<iv=None> for '$420return_value.5', defined at None

Comment: During: typing of assignment at <ipython-input-3-c8fe9f386d86> (37)

File "<ipython-input-3-c8fe9f386d86>", line 37:
def Calcs(Serial,Value,Ref,Base):
    <source elided>
    List = [A,B,Counter]        
    return List
    ^

Comment: This error means that the contiguous array allocated in the Numba function (which are of type `array(float64, 1d, C)`) cannot be converted to a non-contiguous one due to the list sub-typing. I see no reason why Numba could not transform a contiguous array as a non-contiguous one. I think this is a bug of the type inference. You certainly use an outdated Numba implementation. Please check the version with `nb.version_info.full` and update Numba if you have a version older than 0.54.1 (the last is the 0.55.1).

Comment: Note that a simple workaround should be to remove the `List(float64[:])` in the code or to use `List(float64[::1])` instead (to say that the arrays are contiguous).

Comment: Now its working Jérôme Richard. I made changes to Signature as @njit('List(float64[::1])(int64[::1], float64[::1], float64[::1], int64[::1])',fastmath=True). Thank you So much.

Answer (score 0):

This Code is giving list to list convertion typeerror.

```
from numba import njit
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Serial'] = [865,866,867,868,869,870,871,872,873,874,875,876,877,878,879,880]
df['Value'] = [586,586.45,585.95,585.85,585.45,585.5,586,585.7,585.7,585.5,585.5,585.45,585.3,584,584,585]
df['Ref'] = [586.35,586.1,586.01,586.44,586.04,585.91,585.47,585.99,585.35,585.27,585.32,584.86,585.36,584.18,583.53,585]
df['Base'] = [0,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,-1]

@njit('List(float64[:])(float64[:], float64[:], float64[:], float64[:])',fastmath=True)
def Calcs(Serial,Value,Ref,Base):
    n = Base.size
    A = np.empty(n)
    B = np.empty(n)
    Counter = np.empty(n)
    A[0] = 0.0
    B[0] = 0.0
    Counter[0] = Serial[0]
    for i in range(0,n-1):
    # Filling Column 'A'
        if (Ref[i+1] > Value[i+1]) & (B[i] > Value[i+1]) & (Base[i+1] > 0):
            A[i+1] = round((Value[i+1]*1.02),2)
        elif (Ref[i+1] < Value[i+1]) & (B[i] < Value[i+1]) & (Base[i+1] < 0):  
            A[i+1] = round((Value[i+1]*0.98),2)
        else:
            A[i+1] = A[i]
    # Filling Column 'B'
        B[i+1] = round(((Value[i+1] + Ref[i+1])/2),2)
    # Filling Column 'Counter'
        if (B[i+1] > Value[i+1]):
            Counter[i+1] = Serial[i+1]
        else:
           Counter[i+1] = Counter[i]   
    List = [A,B,Counter]        
    return List

Serial = df['Serial'].values
Value = df['Value'].values
Ref = df['Ref'].values
Base = df['Base'].values
VCal = Calcs(Serial, Value, Ref, Base)
df['A'] = VCal[0]
df['B'] = VCal[1]
df['Counter'] = VCal[2]
df
```

Getting the below error.

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No conversion from list(array(float64, 1d, C))<iv=None> to 
list(array(float64, 1d, A))<iv=None> for '$408return_value.5', defined at None

File "<ipython-input-9-3c9e0fe02b75>", line 33:
def Calcs(Serial,Value,Ref,Base):
    <source elided>
    List = [A,B,Counter]        
    return List
    ^

During: typing of assignment at <ipython-input-9-3c9e0fe02b75> (33)

File "<ipython-input-9-3c9e0fe02b75>", line 33:
def Calcs(Serial,Value,Ref,Base):
    <source elided>
    List = [A,B,Counter]        
    return List
    ^
```